# How to add a custom horizontal scroll event to a React material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a slider with arrow icons that allow the user to scroll the material table horizontally. I already did the slider component, but the scroll events in the arrows aren't working yet. I added a tableRef to the material table and tried to use tableEl.current.scrollTo() function, but, unfortunately, it isn't working. So How can I create the eventHandlers to scroll the table horizontally?

[My custom material table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRfWX.png)

My slider component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos';
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIos';

export function TableSlider({ onClickToRigth, onClickToLeft }) {
    return (
      <div style={{ zIndex: 1000, top: "39px", position: "absolute", width: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ArrowBackIosIcon 
          onClick={onClickToLeft} 
          style={{ marginLeft: "4px", cursor: "pointer", opacity: "0.7" }}
         />
        <ArrowForwardIosIcon 
          onClick={onClickToRigth} 
          style={{ cursor: "pointer", opacity: "0.8" }}
         />
      </div>
    )
}
```

My custom material table. Notice that I created a useRef and added it in the material table by doing: tableRef={tableEl}

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { MTableToolbar } from 'material-table';
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';
import { TableSlider } from '../table-slider';

function MyMaterialTable(props) {
  const tableEl = useRef(null);

  const { title, urledit, columns, data, options, deleteItem, rowClick, action } = props;
  var opt = options;
  if (opt == null) {
    opt = {
      sorting: true,
      pageSize: 10,
      showSelectAllCheckbox: true,
      columnsButton: true,
      toolbar: true,
      minBodyHeight: 550,
      paging: false,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderBottom: '2px solid #b3b3b3',
        height: '100px'
      }
    };
  }

  opt.toolbar = false;

  const handleDelete = (data, resolve) => {
    deleteItem(data, resolve);
  };

  const scrollToRigth = () => {
    console.log(tableEl.current)
    // Can i use those functions with a useRef?
    tableEl.current.scrollTo()
    tableEl.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
  };

  const scrollToLeft = () => {
    // Can i use those functions with a useRef?
    tableEl.current.scrollTo()
    tableEl.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
  };

  const intl = props.intl;
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={0} >
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} style={{ position: "relative", display: 'table', tableLayout: 'fixed', width: '100%', minWidth: '210px', paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0 }}>
        <TableSlider onClickToLeft={scrollToLeft} onClickToRigth={scrollToRigth} />
          <MaterialTable
            title={title}
            tableRef={tableEl}
            id="material-table-id"
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            options={opt}
            onRowClick={rowClick}
            actions={action}
            components={{
              Toolbar: props => (
                <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#e8eaf5', color: '#000000' }}>
                  <MTableToolbar {...props} />
                </div>
              ),
            }}
            localization={{
              grouping: {
                groupedBy: intl.formatMessage({ id: "grouped.by" }),
                placeholder: intl.formatMessage({ id: "headers.drap" })
              },
              pagination: {
                labelDisplayedRows: '{from}-{to} ' + intl.formatMessage({ id: "of" }) + ' {count}',
                labelRowsPerPage: intl.formatMessage({ id: "recordsPerPage" }),
                labelRowsSelect: intl.formatMessage({ id: "records" })
              },
              toolbar: {
                addRemoveColumns: intl.formatMessage({ id: "add.remove" }),
                nRowsSelected: '{0}' + intl.formatMessage({ id: "rows.select" }),
                showColumnsTitle: intl.formatMessage({ id: "show.columns" }),
                showColumnsAriaLabel: intl.formatMessage({ id: "show.columns" }),
                exportTitle: intl.formatMessage({ id: "export" }),
                exportAriaLabel: intl.formatMessage({ id: "export" }),
                exportName: intl.formatMessage({ id: "export.csv" }),
                searchTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "search" }),
                searchPlaceholder: intl.formatMessage({ id: "search" })
              },
              header: {
                actions: ''
              },
              body: {
                emptyDataSourceMessage: intl.formatMessage({ id: "rows.show" }),
                filterRow: {},
                editRow: {
                  saveTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "save" }),
                  cancelTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "cancel" }),
                  deleteText: intl.formatMessage({ id: "sure.delete" })
                },
                addTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "add" }),
                deleteTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "delete" }),
                editTooltip: intl.formatMessage({ id: "update" })
              }
            }}
          />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default injectIntl(MyMaterialTable);

MyMaterialTable.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  urledit: PropTypes.string,
  columns: PropTypes.array,
  data: PropTypes.array,
  options: PropTypes.object,
  deleteItem: PropTypes.func,
  rowClick: PropTypes.func,
  action: PropTypes.func
};
```

Here is my problem, I don't know how to use the ref to scroll my table horizontally. tableEl.current.scrollTo() and tableEl.current.scrollIntoView() returns undefined

```js
  const scrollToRigth = () => {
    console.log(tableEl.current)
    // Can i use those functions with a useRef?
    tableEl.current.scrollTo()
    tableEl.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
  };

  const scrollToLeft = () => {
    // Can i use those functions with a useRef?
    tableEl.current.scrollTo()
    tableEl.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
  };
```